# Указать прилагательное, которое пишется с НЕ всегда раздельно

Tags: орфография, грамматика, прилагательные, учебное-задание

Укажите прилагательное, которое пишется с НЕ всегда раздельно. Почему?

> Не стройный, не лунный, не нужный, не
> здоровый, не удачный.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Не лунный", потому что живущим на Земле пока не было необходимости приписывать чему-либо такое качество как "нелунность". А отрицать отдельной частицей "лунное" происхождение принесённых минералов иногда приходится. Вот если для постоянно живущих на Луне русский язык станет основным, там могут возникнуть "нелунные" страсти местного значения :)

Comment: Мне тоже так показалось вначале..только вот я дала поиск на слово-нелунный,и к удивлению я встретила его на нескольких сайтах,это и ввело меня в затруднение

Comment: Мало ли что понапишут на сайтах, сейчас много неграмотных людей, там даже "нелунный же это свет" написано, но это-то явная ошибка. Правило гласит: не с относительными прилагательными всегда пишется раздельно.Знания этого правила от Вас и ждали. Ответ верен, не обращайте внимания на сайты, это не авторитет.